# Android Studio stuck in setup wizard ,what to do?

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyf9Z.jpg)

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio is heavy IDE and takes lot of of time for initial setup.
a couple of things:

1. Make sure you got good strong wifi
2. If you're on VPN, disconnect it.
3. stop other stuff if you're downloading
4. last resort is to shutdown and restart.